# Objective-C Properties and Pointers to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pointers, properties

I just started learning Swift and I have been consulting Apple's Dev Guide but some of the syntax when dealing with properties and pointers is throwing me off. Apple explains that properties just use dot syntax and even the API seems to reflect that but it's not working to my desired to effect. Here's what I've been working on specifically. I am also struggling with instance initialization.  *I have already properly created a bridging header* Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is the code I am trying to emulate in swift.

```
@property (nonatomic) SFWaterNode *waterSurface;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastUpdateTime;
@end

@implementation GameScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-1, self.size.height/2);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(self.size.width, self.size.height/2);

    self.waterSurface = [SFWaterNode nodeWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint depth:self.size.height/2 color:[SKColor blueColor]];
    [self addChild:self.waterSurface];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    [self.waterSurface splash:location speed:-50];
}

- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    [self.waterSurface update:currentTime];
}

@end
```

Comment: you should really learn swift's syntax .

Comment: I know some Swift - the code I included is Obj-C

Comment: alright simpler question - how does this translate to swift: @property (nonatomic) SFWaterNode *waterSurface;

Comment: That woudl be `public var waterSurface: SFWaterNode`. A property is just a variable in Swift. You can add a get/set method if needed, but don't have to. (I end up using didSet a lot more than I use a custom setter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
public var waterSurface:SFWaterNode?
var lastUpdateTime:NSTimeInterval

func didMoveToView(view:SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = .black

    let startPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.init(x: -1, y: self.size.height/2)
    let endPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -1, y: self.size.height/2)

    self.waterSurface = SFWaterNode.nodeWithStartPoint(startPoint, endPoint:endPoint, depth:self.size.height/2, color:.blue)

    self.addChild(self.waterSurface)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject()
    let location:CGPoint = touch.location(inNode: self)
    self.waterSurface.splash(location, speed:-50)

}

func update(curentTime:CFTimeInterval) {

    self.waterSurface.update(currentTime)
}
```

Comment: Don't explicitly add type annotations if it's it can obviously be inferred. Like for example: `let startPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.init(x: -1, y: self.size.height/2)` should just be `let startPoint= CGPoint(x: -1, y: self.size.height/2)`

Comment: With a few minor adjustments - this worked perfectly. Thank you